# Method Of Successive Approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Are there any differences between a method of successive approximation and Picard method of successive approximation. As in, for example, let $y'=y$ ; $y(0)=1$. Solve the IVP using the method of successive approx. Does this means Picard's Method?

Comment: Pls, any help on this?

Comment: Did this answer resolve your issues?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this means Picard Iteration.

The term MOSA is used in a lot of contexts like Newton's root finding method, for example.

Here we have:

- $y_0(x)= 1 $
- $\displaystyle y_1(x) = y_0 + \int_0^x f(x, y_0)~dx = 0 + \int_0^x y~ dx = 1 + x$
- $\displaystyle y_2(x) = y_0 + \int_0^x f(x, y_1)~dx = 1+ \int_0^x (1+x) ~dx = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2}$
- $y_3(x) =$ Your turn

Note that if you continue this process, you should be able to determine the closed form of this DEQ (this does not always work out depending on the complexity of the ODE), that is, find $y_n(x)$.

If we find the closed form of this ODE, we get:

$$y(x) = e^x$$

You should be able to easily derive this using MOSA (Picard Iteration).

Comment: Also needs a TU! +1

Comment: I know, Amzoti. I'm just hanging in to get to 100K. After that, I will most definitely reassess my participation here!